# How do I log into kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I have an Elastic cluster at https://www.elastic.co/. I enabled Kibana, but then when I click Kibana, it prompts me to enter in a user/password.

My login to the normal Elastic cluster doesn't work -- is there a default user/password that I can enter, or how do I actually get into my Kibana dashboard? Ideally, I would just like to disable having to login (so just clicking the Kibana dashboard goes into it) -- is there a way to do that?

Comment: Have you tried elastic/changeme ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you were creating your cluster, you were given a password with UID: elastic. It should have warned you that you needed to save the password as you cannot retrieve it. If you have not saved it, you will need to generate a new password from the Security tab on the left within the cluster.

When you login into Kibana, you can create more users through Management > Elasticsearch: Security > Create User.